# How does one remove a file from a FlashAir card using the API?

Tags: python, http, web, flashair

On the basis of the documentation for [command.cgi](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/commandcgi/#100) and [upload.cgi](https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/uploadcgi/#DELETE), I have a simple sync application that first retrieves a list of files and then tries to delete them from the device.

However, the delete operation always fails with a 404 error.

The request being issued is like

```
GET /upload.cgi?DEL=/DCIM/109___06/IMG_0611.JPG HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
User-Agent: ...
```

The file given as argument to `DEL` certainly exists on the device since the value is taken directly from a file list response immediately prior.

The full response from the FlashAir API is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>404 Not Found</H1>
The requested URL was not found on this server.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `http://192.168.0.1/upload.cgi` certainly exist? Since `404 Not Found` is displayed, there is a possibility that you can not access the API URL in the first place.

Comment: Oh, that's a very good thought.  Requests for `/upload.cgi` also fail with a 404!  Hmmm.

Comment: With this in mind, re-reading the upload docs, I think that all of upload.cgi must be disabled by default and to use it it has to be enabled by writing UPLOAD=1 to the config.  My prior reading of those docs led me to believe only actual uploads required this setting...